# Browser back-button when a list of values selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to keep the list of values from drop-down selections when the browser back-button is click after the form has been submitted. I tried using Ben Alman's bbq jquery, but failed to get things working. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/FQP9Q/7/) what I've been trying. Please help.

Many thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<form action="something.py" id="formName">
    <table id = "tabName">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th><th>Number</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select id="myname" name="myname">
                    <option value="a">a</option>
                    <option value="b">b</option>
                    <option value="c">c</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="mynumber" name="mynumber">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

JQuery:

```
var selected_value = [];
$('#mynumber').change(function() {
    var name = $('#myname').val();
    var number = $('#mynumber').val();

    $("#tabName tr:last").before("<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + number + "</td></tr>");
    selected_value.push(name);
});

$('#formName').submit(function() {
    $.bbq.pushState({
        values: selected_value
    });
    //return false;
});

$(window).bind("hashchange", function(e) {
    var values = $.bbq.getState("url");
    if (selected_value === values) {
        $(this).addClass("current");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("current");
    }
});
```

Comment: Put your code here please, rather than just link to jsfiddle

Comment: Have you tried any cookies/localStorage solution?

Comment: @DGT can't you simply send these values back from the server on page refresh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution (without cookies or localStorage) based on location.hash:

```
function addRow(name, number){
    $("#tabName tr:last").before("<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + number + "</td></tr>");
}

$(function(){
    if(location.hash){
        var rows = location.hash.substr(1).split(';');
        for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
            var row = rows[i].split(',');
            if(row.length == 2){
                addRow(row[0], row[1]);
            }
        }
    }

    $('#mynumber').change(function() {
        var name = $('#myname').val();
        var number = $('#mynumber').val();
        location.hash = location.hash + (location.hash ? ';' : '') + name + ',' + number;
        addRow(name, number);
    });
});
```

I think it does what you have asked for - if not, please give me some feedback in comments.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot. Sorry, couldn't get back to you earlier.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to click on the bounty icon.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#formName').submit(function() {
    $.bbq.pushState({
        values: selected_value
    });
    //return false;
});
```

should be

```
$('#formName').submit(function() {
    $.bbq.pushState({
        values: selected_value
    });
    //return false;
});
```

and

```
var values = $.bbq.getState("url");
```

should be

```
var values = $.bbq.getState("values");
```

Comment: ad. 1 JS object silently converts all keys to string, so you do not to put "everywhere"